# Office Addin Debugging Ensure the url is accessible

Tags: angular, office365, office-js, office-addins

I am getting this error event though i can access the xml file from `https://localhost:4200/manifest.xml` Even when i serve as `127.0.0.1:4200/manifest.xml` but than it doesnt work because i dont have a certificate for that ip. I am testing locally. Is there a way to specify a url where `office-addin-debugging` will look for manifest file.

[image]

I was able to make it work by running angular like this

```
npm run start -- --host 127.0.0.1 --port 4200
or
ng s --host 127.0.0.1 --port 4200
```

But i really dont want to do that

Also command i use to run debuger is:

```
office-addin-debugging start path/to/manifest.xml web --document <url>
```

It could be connected to this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Office-WordExcel-Addin-is-not-opening-f/10533893?space=41&sort=newest

Answer (score -1):

You're combining a a few things here and I'd reccomend breaking them apart.

You need a `webserver` and then you need to launch `debugging`.

You say you got it to work via:

---

```
npm run start -- --host 127.0.0.1 --port 4200
```

or

```
ng s --host 127.0.0.1 --port 4200
```

But i really dont want to do that

---

I'm not sure why you don't want to do that?

Your flow should be "start a webserver" via:

```
ng s --host 127.0.0.1 --port 4200
```

Then start debugging via:

```
office-addin-debugging start path/to/manifest.xml web --document <url>
```

office-addin-debugging is NOT meant to launch a webserver process, that should already be running. I don't think anything is wrong with your setup if the above works for you.

Note: If you're SSL certificate is for localhost or 127.0.0.1 and one or the other is causing issues, instead of trying to fix your certificate, adjust the manifest to match whatever URL is working in the browser. But in my local setup, I can use either or without SSL error.